# How to increase the width of nav without breaking responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building with grids for the first time and wanted to stretch the bootstrap nav element to so that the links are wider. I can't quite recreate it in the fiddle exactly:

http://jsfiddle.net/yjyTq/

Basically I want to the nav elements to be a bit larger and the entire nav area to fill the 6 columns specified, but when I over-ride the bootstrap code the nav li elements won't stack up when the browser is narrowed.

```
.nav{
    width:100%;
}

.nav-pills>li{
    width:23%;
    font-size:1.1em;
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this without breaking everything?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add `padding-left` and `padding-right` to your `nav li a` elements to increase the size of the `li`

So this:

```
.nav-pills>li>a {
    text-align:center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yjyTq/1/

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I wouldn't have thought to use px but it works fine and keeps the buttons a nice size even when resizing.